# OC4J 10.1.3.3 unable to find ojms.rar setting up database persistences

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, jms

I'm running into problems with JMS in Oracle AS 10.1.3.3.

The error I am getting is 'connectors\ojms.rar (The system cannot find the path specified)' from EM.

Below are a few bullets on the environment.

- This is on a Windows XP SP3 machine.
- All configuration is through EM.
- The EM is a local instance that has been used for over a year.
- This instance has existing db connection management exposed through JNDI.
- Oracle_home is set to the directory where I unzip the OC4J zip file. c:\oc4j_10.1.3.3.
- ojms.rar file is in %ORACLE_HOME%\j2ee\home\connectors

**Configuring OC4J for JMS with Database Persistence**
I've create a new data connection for Oracle AQ and exposed the connection through JNDI as jms/flexc

When creating the Resource Adapter through EM, I'm providing the following information:
Resource Name: JMS on FlexC
Adding a new resource
             Name : jmsFlexc
  Datasource JNDI : jms/flexc    (selected from dropdown box)

Very quickly, I get the error below:

```
An error has occurred.
connectors\ojms.rar (The system cannot find the path specified)
connectors\ojms.rar (The system cannot find the path specified)
[Select to hide information] Hide Additional Trace Information
oracle.sysman.ias.studio.j2ee.deploy.DeployUtil$DeploymentFailureException at
oracle.sysman.ias.studio.j2ee.deploy.DeployUtil.deployArchive(DeployUtil.java:211) at
oracle.sysman.ias.studio.j2ee.deploy.DeployUtil.deployArchive(DeployUtil.java:85) at
oracle.sysman.ias.studio.oc4j.jms.JMXDeployDbProviderAdminBean.deployDBProviderAndConfigure(JMXDeployDbProviderAdminBean.java:121) at
oracle.sysman.ias.studio.oc4j.jms.DeployDbProviderHelper.deployDBProvider(DeployDbProviderHelper.java:242) at
oracle.sysman.ias.studio.oc4j.jms.DeployDbProviderHelper.handleEvent(DeployDbProviderHelper.java:127) at
oracle.sysman.ias.studio.sdk.AbstractController.handleEvent(AbstractController.java:769) at
oracle.sysman.emSDK.svlt.PageHandler.handleRequest(PageHandler.java:378) at
oracle.sysman.emSDK.svlt.EMServlet.myDoGet(EMServlet.java:765) at
oracle.sysman.emSDK.svlt.EMServlet.doGet(EMServlet.java:283) at
oracle.sysman.ias.studio.app.StudioConsole.doGet(StudioConsole.java:385) at
oracle.cabo.servlet.UIXServlet.doPost(Unknown Source) at
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763) at
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856) at
com.evermind.server.http.ResourceFilterChain.doFilter(ResourceFilterChain.java:65) at
oracle.sysman.ias.studio.app.BrowserVersionFilter.doFilter(BrowserVersionFilter.java:75) at
com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:15) at
oracle.sysman.ias.studio.app.MultipleJVMFilter.doFilter(MultipleJVMFilter.java:85) at
com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:17) at
oracle.sysman.ias.studio.app.PostLogonFilter.doFilter(PostLogonFilter.java:80) at
com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:17) at
oracle.sysman.ias.studio.app.ShortHostnameRedirectFilter.doFilter(ShortHostnameRedirectFilter.java:68) at
com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:621) at
com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:370) at
com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:871) at
com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:453) at
com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.serveOneRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:221) at
com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:122) at
com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:111) at
oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260) at
oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler.procClientSocket(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:239) at
oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler.access$700(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:34) at
oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler$AcceptHandlerHorse.run(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:880) at
com.evermind.util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:303) at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) Caused by: oracle.oc4j.admin.jmx.shared.exceptions.JMXRuntimeException: connectors\ojms.rar (The system cannot find the path specified) at
oracle.oc4j.admin.jmx.shared.util.JarTool.(JarTool.java:122) at
oracle.sysman.ias.studio.j2ee.deploy.DeployPageUtil.getArchiveType(DeployPageUtil.java:105) at
oracle.sysman.ias.studio.j2ee.deploy.DeployUtil.deployArchive(DeployUtil.java:133) ... 33 more Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: connectors\ojms.rar (The system cannot find the path specified) at
java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) at
java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:114) at
java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:135) at
java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:99) at
oracle.oc4j.admin.jmx.shared.util.JarTool.(JarTool.java:119) ... 35 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that this is a bug in OC4J.

The solution was found by a colleague as a comment made to [this blog](http://mike-lehmann.blogspot.com/2006/09/simple-mdb-with-oracle-database-jms.html)

> I also got an error when deploying the
>   resource adapter. I found that this
>   was a bug in Oracle Standalone
>   10.1.3.3.0 (bug 6786060 on Metalink) and can be solved either by using
>   10.1.3.2.0 or by starting Oracle standalone without the ORACLE_HOME
>   environment variable. This is made by
>   the command "java -jar oc4j.jar". I
>   used the last solution and it worked
>   fine for me.