# How do I create an MDB that listens to Oracle AQ queue under JBoss AS?

Tags: jms, jboss5.x, message-driven-bean, oracle-aq

I need to listen to an Oracle AQ queue in a Java EE application that runs under JBoss AS 5.1.

I managed to create a regular JMS client using Oracle's JMS client library, but since this is a Java EE application, I'd really like to use a MDB.

I can't really find any documentation on this, and I can't find a resource adapter that lets me do this using JCA.

Can anyone tell me what's required to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

This [JBoss Community Posting](http://community.jboss.org/message/230056) outlines how to do this. 
I am not sure *exactly* which RAR to use, but my Oracle DB install contains these:

- product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\oc4j\j2ee\home\connectors\ojms.rar
- product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\oc4j\j2ee\home\connectors\OracleASjms\OracleASjms.rar

This [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856824/oc4j-10-1-3-3-unable-to-find-ojms-rar-setting-up-database-persistences) question links to an extensive blog on the topic as well.

Comment: Yes, I found that post as well, but it still doesn't tell me where to find the rar :-(

Comment: Also: that SO question is about a missing rar ;-)